# How can I create a restricted Python subset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, restriction

I want to create a restricted subset of Python 3, or if you can't answer that, something to block functions, keywords, classes, and that kind of stuff.
I also just want to allow certain things and that's it. I don't want to have to write a bunch of things to **block**, just want to write things to **allow**.

I already know how to run a program from an argument, like:

```sh
mypython test.py
```

The code for that is:

```py
from sys import argv

codefile = open(argv[1], "rt")
code = codefile.read()
codefile.close()
```

And to restrict something:

```py
del something
```

but that does not work for functions. I tested that with `print` and it sayed:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    del print
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```

So, can you show me something to accomplish this? I am on Fedora 34 **Beta** to influence anything.

Comment: you could parse the input file with `ast` and search for disallowed nodes before passing to `eval`...

Comment: @Aaron `ast` is weird

Comment: abstract syntax trees are how most languages are parsed... if you want to effectively make your own language you'll have to play with the syntax tree at some level.

Comment: @Aaron I made a programming language before but it uses `.split`...